# What concise words or sentence would be the response to somebody telling you how they feel about you and that you feel the same way about them?

Tags: phrase-requests

Somebody told me they like me because of the way I have always treated them. My response was "I feel the same". They then said "Oh, you like the way you treat me and like yourself too because of that?" Which was a cheeky and friendly retort as we've been close friends since school and we're now in our 50s, but I wasn't able to rephrase my reply quickly enough (or at all) to block the swipe.

Any smart answers that could have been my smart answer at the time would be appreciated.

Comment: Your response was fine. As you noted, your friend was just being cheeky.

Comment: They were just making a silly joke. They understood you perfectly.

Comment: They're (jokingly) quibbling with an apparently unintended meaning in your reply, but your question title also contains an apparently unintended meaning. It seems to say that the other person is not only telling you "how they feel about you" but also "that you feel the same way about them". Why would they be telling you how you feel?

Answer (score 1):

"ditto" is the obvious short response. The phenomenon is reciprocity.

Answer (score 1):

"The feeling is ***mutual***."

> mutual (adjective)
>
> 1. (of a feeling or action) experienced or done by each of two or more parties towards the other or others.
>    "a partnership based on mutual respect and understanding"

(Oxford Languages)

The meaning behind your comment are fairly obvious, so it was nothing but a bit of playful banter. A good reply would also something equally playful like "Yes, I like myself almost as much as I like you" or something depending on your intentions...

Answer (score 0):

Of course, they understood you perfectly and were making a joke. But if you want to absolutely exclude the alternate interpretation, you could say: "I feel the same about you, ***mutatis mutandis***." This is a term most common in legal contexts; [Collins defines it as](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/mutatis-mutandis) "with all due adjustments or modifications having been made." More specifically, it usually means that you need to swap around *all* the words in a sentence to fit a new situation, in this case yielding "I like you because of the way you have treated me."

Comment: Once you include "about you", there's no need for the additional qualification.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, concise way to respond would be *vice versa*. From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vice%20versa)

> with the order changed : with the relations reversed